# jQuery parseHTML() is not working

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I need to render html content as html, but it is rendering as string text.

```
$('#description').html($.parseHTML('<%=event.description%>'));
```

jQuery add the text as string, it is not rendering the HTML tags, if `blog.description` contains paragraph, bold, italic and other HTML elements it renders in pure text.

Description content is not stored as escaped HTML, is just in pure HTML.

Thanks in advance

**## EDIT ##**

I'm not using .NET Framework, just Node.JS with Express and EJS template engine.

I store the description field in DB as both methods:

**:: Decoded:**

```
"<p> example <b>text</b> </p>"
```

**:: Undecoded:**

```
"&lt;p&gt; example &lt;b&gt;text&lt;&#x2F;b&gt; &lt;&#x2F;p&gt;"
```

Unfortunately both ways don't make the text to be correctly displayed as HTML into signed div.

I resorted to jQuery because the first attempt to load the text directly from DB didn't work.

I've tried:

```
$('#description').html( MY TEXT ).text();

$('#description').text( MY TEXT ).html();

$('#description').html( $.parseHTML(MY TEXT) );
```

Doesn't work. However if I get the description text and copy and make it render by myself (avoiding DB) it displays correctly.

The picture shows what is going on:

[image]

Any extra tip will be helpful.

Comment: Did you try that without the `$.parseHTML` to see if it works ?

Comment: The HTML is rendering as scaped: <b>name</b> is rendering as b&gt;name&nbsp;&lt;/b , I have tried without `$.parseHTML()` but the same result happens.

Comment: When I try to use `WebUtility` how you mentioned it doens't work, na error is raised.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the `<%= %>` tags and assumed it was .Net

Comment: '<%=event.description%>' is not HTML, it's EJS.
Before parsing you need to render() it with an EJS template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still believe that issue is with your text being HTML encoded in your DB and somewhere along the way back, and you need to decode before displaying on screen. Unfortunately I do not know node.js and what the equivalent method for `WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` in .Net is. (Hopefully someone else can answer this for you).

As a hack, you can do the following, but I would not recommend it, it is a workaround at best:

[Encode or Decode HTML entities with jQuery](http://www.naveen.com.au/javascript/jquery/encode-or-decode-html-entities-with-jquery/289)

```
var mytext = '<%=event.description%>';
var decoded = $('<div />').html(mytext).text();
$('#description').html(decoded);
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/2u9YU/)

Comment: Thanks, jam mykam, it worked for me. I don't know why have to decode the text into div so get it and put it into after description div, but worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows.

```
$('#description').html($('<%=event.description%>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to assign it as html to element, you not need to parse it as html. It will automatically be parsed but if you setting it as text and want to assign html there you need parsing.

so try this:

```
$('#description').html('<%=event.description%>');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fit my problem. I've updated the thread.